# How can I show the Title and Legend of a ZedGraph when running application on Mono on Mac?

Tags: c#, mono, zedgraph

I have a Winforms application that we are getting to work on Mono so we can run it on Mac. The application makes heavy use of ZedGraph, which is written entirely in C#.

ZedGraph works perfectly on Windows (obviously) and seems to work perfectly on Linux, but when I run the application on Mac OS X I get a nonsense graph. Essentially no data is visible.

[No Data](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/screenshot20130517at511.png/)

If I make the title and legend invisible, I can plot and see the data points at least, but the labels of the X and Y axes, as well as the units, are not visible.

[No Axes, Title, nor Legend](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/screenshot20130517at512.png/)

```
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Title.IsVisible = false;
        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Legend.IsVisible = false;
```

This is better than no data at all, but ideally I want to have a legend, a title, and at the very least see the labels and units on the axes. Has anyone had any succesful experience using ZedGraph on Mac OS through Mono?

Comment: What you could do is upload your image somewhere like http://imageshack.us/, then put the link in your post. That is always possible.

Comment: Yes, good idea. I just added links to two images, thanks.

Comment: this might be a bit late... but still might help you. This kind of beaviour look like an exception is thrown and fail silently. this trigger the onpaint so your getting a part of your graph drawn